# Debian lenny GUI not working

Tags: debian, gui, debian-lenny

I have installed the Debian "lenny" release on my machine. The GUI is not working in normal mode; to start it I have to go to single user mode and type:

```
gdm start
```

Why is this happening? Any ideas would be appreciated. Do you need any further information?

Comment: I'm curious why you are using Lenny, instead of the newer Squeeze (Debian 6).

Comment: Yes, we need further information. E.g. what happens when you run "telinit 5" as root...

Comment: @Turbo J:If i run telinit 5 it says starting common printing system(cupsd) and nothing happening.It struck while starting cupsd.